# Custom Android RatingBar with 10 stars (used in the Badoo App for Android)

Tags: android, widget, custom-controls, seekbar, ratingbar

I have tried to duplicate the same custom RatingBar used in the Badoo App

http://s16.postimg.org/7l6dxqsr9/badoo_screens.png

Badoo App to download at:
play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.badoo.mobile&hl=en

The RatingBar has 10 stars with number into each one and fits perfectly no matter the size of the screen or in landscape mode

http://s16.postimg.org/4sd6dpset/device_2013_05_12_221153.png

Also, there is a animation on the current selected star (rating) as soon as you touch the Rating bar. The star grows up and turn back to the normal size when pressed. On the middle of the screen a dialog box appears too showing the current selection pressed (disappear a few seconds later after selected the rating).

I was wondering if someone would have similar RatingBar or if someone could help me how to develop that. I searched some samples but not like this particular case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will open source some parts of it very soon and I will post here a link to the repository.

[EDIT] You can now browse the source, use it under MIT licence and see an example app here: https://github.com/badoo/StarBar

Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Hi. When would be possible you to post the link for the source code for this particular widget? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good starting point: http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/

As for the animation, you may implement an `OnRatingBarChangeListener` to detect which star (or rating) was selected and animate the specific star.